# Making a grid for a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a grid for a 2d array for a hw assignment and not sure if this is the correct way to format it.This is my code:

```
  public void showSeats() {

    System.out.print(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < p[0].length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("|%10d|", i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < p[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.printf("|%10s|", p[i][j].getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

basically I need to be using the correct formatting of printf and for loops. If there is an easier way please do tell. The output should look like this:

```
 output:

 |         0||         1|
0|Passenger1||Passenger2|
1|Passenger3||Passenger4|
```

errors:

```
Estimate of Problem Coverage (63%)
Problem coverage: 63%

For this assignment, the proportion of the problem that is covered by your solution is being assessed by running a suite of reference tests against your solution.

Test results indicate that your code still contains bugs. Your code appears to cover only 63% of the behavior required for this assignment.

Double check that you have carefully followed all initial conditions requested in the assignment in setting up your solution, and that you have also met all requirements for a complete solution in the final state of your program.

The following hint(s) may help you locate some ways in which your solution may be improved:

Test 4: 'remove' example output mismatch at line 9 Expected: | 0|| 1| Actual: | 0|| 1|

Test 2: 'seats' example output mismatch at line 6 Expected: | 0|| 1| Actual: | 0|| 1|

Test 3: 'add' example output mismatch at line 9 Expected: | 0|| 1| Actual: | 0|| 1|
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're currently doing?

Comment: When i enter it in webcat(automatic grader) it says there is an error, I'll post the error its giving me

Comment: Looks like the grader is messed up, unless the spaces it uses in `Expected` are different from the spaces you used in `Actual`, as in different unicode whitespace.

Comment: I figured it was the grader, I emailed my teacher and he told me to check my printf statements, he also said it should look something like this for (int i = 0; i < pax.length; i++) {
            // Display the row label
            System.out.printf("%2d", i);

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. I imagine it's something to do with an invisible character somewhere? - Talk to your teach about it.

Comment: Oh then change the `printf` statement from `%10d` to `%2d` and try submitting again.

Comment: It still doesnt work when i do that and its supposed to be 10 dimensions wide, I'll email him about it again I just thought maybe theres an easier way to format it that I don't know about